# Display a 'Load Time' seconds for an AJAX page in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

My page consists of a pretty simple table that pulls data from a database. The page load time I have is in Application controller  Ihave

```
def set_start_time
  @start_time = Time.now.usec
end
```

And then on the page I have

> Page Rendered: <%= sprintf('%.3f', (Time.now.usec - @start_time).abs / 1000000.0) %> seconds

BUT, because the table loads separately from the page I cannot get the number I want for the real load time. IE how long will it take for the user to load 100 records (without going and looking at the server log). How can I accomplish this?

Ideally I would like to display it on top of the page

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you want to do this through the ruby, you can do this very easily using ajax.

```
var start_time = new Date.getTime();  // getTime gives you timestamp
$.ajax({
  url: YOUR_URL,
  success: function() {
   // Do what you want on succee of this function 
  }
  error: function(){
  // Do what you want on error
  }
  complete: function(){
  // This function is triggered on completion of ajax call
  end_time = new Date.getTime();
  diff_time = end_time -start_time;
  $(selector).html(diff_time);  // selector is place where you want to display time
  }
});
```

I think this will help you.

Thanks